# How to count duplicates values in NSArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, duplicates

Value of my `NSArray` includes the duplicates.
I find the duplicates but now how can I find the no. they repeat?

Comment: How are you finding the duplicates? If you're stepping through the array values and comparing them, you should be able to incriment an int whenever you hit a duplicate value.

Comment: NSArray *cleanedArray = [[NSSet setWithArray:duplicateElements] allObjects];  By this code I remove duplicates.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think you're going to be able to get a count out of that method. Look at @omz suggestion, it seems like it's going to work a treat. Then you can call the `[[NSSet setWithArray:duplicateElements] allObjects];` methods.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use [`NSCountedSet`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCountedSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for this. Add all your objects to a counted set, then use the `countForObject:` method to find out how often each object appears.

Comment: Actually, I'll just +1 this answer and bookmark it in Chrome.

Answer (score 9):

**Example:**

```
NSArray *names = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"John", @"Jane", @"John", nil];
NSCountedSet *set = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:names];

for (id item in set) {

    NSLog(@"Name=%@, Count=%lu", item, (unsigned long)[set countForObject:item]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
__block NSInteger elementCount = 0;
NSArray *array;

[<#NSArray yourArray#> indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
    if (obj == <#yourObject#>) {
        elementCount++;
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}];
```

Let me know if that works for you