# How to Find Duplicate Values in Arrays?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.2, ios-simulator

I am working on SQLite and I have written a query which returns me two arrays ItemsArray and CustomersIDArray as:

```
ItemsArray
Element at Index 0 = Off White,
Element at Index 1 = Fan,
Element at Index 2 = Off White,
Element at Index 3 = Delux,
Element at Index 4 = Fan

CustomerIDArray 
Element at Index 0 = 1,
Element at Index 1 = 2,
Element at Index 2 = 2,
Element at Index 3 = 3,
Element at Index 4 = 4
```

I want result like that Off White = 2 (count) , Fan = 2 (count) and Delux = 1; 
and the Resultant Array,

```
Result Array 
Element at Index 0 = Off White,
Element at Index 1 = Fan,
Element at Index 2 = Delux
```

Actually I want the count of repetition in first array but the value must not same for CustomerArray.
Please help me through logic or code.

Comment: Try solution provided on this question: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841072/how-to-count-duplicates-values-in-nsarray)

Comment: @INoob Dear I don't know how to use NSCountedSet.. Can you please tell me ?

Comment: Try the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7606138/876283

Comment: @iNoob how to count the repeated elements count :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
-(NSMutableArray *)getCountAndRemoveMultiples:(NSMutableArray *)array{

    NSMutableArray *newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:(NSArray *)array];
    NSMutableArray *countArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    int countInt = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < newArray.count; ++i) {
        NSString *string = [newArray objectAtIndex:i];
        for (int j = i+1; j < newArray.count; ++j) {
            if ([string isEqualToString:[newArray objectAtIndex:j]]) {
                [newArray removeObjectAtIndex:j];
                countInt++;
            }
        }
        [countArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:countInt]];
        countInt = 1;
    }
    NSMutableArray *finalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:newArray, countArray, nil];
    NSLog(@"%@", finalArray);
    return finalArray;

}
- (IBAction)getArrayInfo:(id)sender {
    NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Off White", @"Fan", @"Off White", @"Deluxe", @"Fan", nil];
    NSMutableArray *godArray = [self getCountAndRemoveMultiples:myArray];
    NSLog(@"Array from this end = %@", godArray);
}
```

I just set up -getArrayInfo to test it out.  Works fine.  As you can see, the array you want to display will be at index:0, and the countArray at index:1.

Comment: its really nice work I commit some changes according to me... Thumbs up :)

Comment: I have another problem can you help me?

Comment: Sure-- post a question, and leave a link to it as a comment here.

Comment: the above answser is logically incorrect. try with this input     NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Off White", @"Fan", @"Fan", @"Off White", @"Deluxe", @"Fan", @"Fan", nil]; . you can see count of "fan" is 3 but actually it is four. To correct this issue you need to decrement j after an element is removed from array (otherwise the next string in the array is not evaluated). edited the answer

Answer (score 2):

Use `NSCountedSet` like below

```
NSMutableArray *ary_res = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"11",@"13",@"34",@"9",@"13",@"34",@"9",@"2",nil];
    NSCountedSet *set = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:array];
    for(id name in set)
    {
        if([set countForObject:name]==2)
            [ary_res addObject:name];
    }
    //
    NSLog(@"%@",ary_res);
```

Comment: I need result in Array if two time then save 2 again that item if three the save 3 if one then 1.

Comment: Yes ... but also want to know how many times it comes in the Array

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
NSArray *copy = [ItemsArray copy];

NSInteger index = [copy count] - 1;

for (id object in [copy reverseObjectEnumerator]) {

    if ([ItemsArray indexOfObject:object inRange:NSMakeRange(0, index)] != NSNotFound) {
        [ItemsArray removeObjectAtIndex:index];
    }
    index--;
}
```

Comment: I Change it and its works for me. its update Items Array. But i also want Count of Repeated items.

Comment: I suggest not to use the name copy to the array as people can get confused with the message copy you also used in: NSArray *copy = [ItemsArray copy];