# Check duplicate property values of objects in NSArray

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, search, nsarray

I have an `NSArray` containing objects with a `size` property.

How can I check if the `NSArray` has two objects with the same value for `size`?

Can I do something like:

```
int i = 0;
for (id item1 in myArray) {
    NSDecimalNumber *size1 = [item1 size];

    for (id item2 in myArray) {
        NSDecimalNumber *size2 = [item2 size];

        if ([size1 isEqual:size2]) {
            i ++;
        }
    }
}

if (i > [myArray count]) {
    NSLog(@"Duplicate Sizes Exist");
}
```

Or is there an easier way?

Comment: You can do the above, but it's "N-squared" and generally considered poor form for larger collections.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
NSSet *myset = [NSSet setWithArray:[myarray valueForKey:@"size"]];
int duplicatesCount = [myarray count] - [myset count];
```

`size` here is the object property.

Comment: You can also use KVC collection operators: [myArray valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.size"]. More details here: http://nshipster.com/kvc-collection-operators/

Answer (score 1):

Use [NSCountedSet](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCountedSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html). then add all your objects to the counted set, and use the `countForObject`: method to find out how often each object appears in your array.

You can check this link also [how-to-find-duplicate-values-in-arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10280676/how-to-find-duplicate-values-in-arrays)

Hope it helps you

Comment: Yeah, but the objects may be different but have the same size. So the array my have 2 objects which are size 3, but one is brown and one is grey. Your suggestion would only pick up identical objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *cleanedArray = [[NSSet setWithArray:yourArraywithDuplicatesObjects ] allObjects];
```

Use Sets this will remove all duplicates objects.Will return NSArray[NSCountedSet](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCountedSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and use `countForObject:` method to find out how often each object appears how many times.

Comment: I knew there would be a lot of suggestions to use NSSet, but I don't have duplicate objects, just need to check if any objects have the same propert value :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably simplest is to sort the array based on the size field and then step through the sorted list looking for adjacent dupes.

You could also "wrap" each object in one that exports the size as its key and use a set.  But that's a lot of extra allocations.

But if you only want to know if dupes exist, and not which ones they are, create an NSNumber for each object's size and insert the NSNumbers in a set.  The final size will tell you how many dupes.

Comment: That's a good suggestion as the array is already sorted. Thanks Hot Licks :)